# MS Excel, select data from cells

Tags: excel

I have a Microsoft excel database that contains patients dates when these patients are supposed come back for review, i need to design an appointment application that would help me know which patients are to be reviewed in a certain period e.g from 25/06/2012 to 29/06/2012. i would like to design this application in Excel using VBA but don't know the code that can help me select these dates in the database so that i can generate a report.

thanks

Comment: See `AutoFilter` in Excel VBA Help.

Comment: do you want to generate a schedule for who will need reviews or something? It is difficult to know what you want. Or as @Scott suggests, will autofilter for a custom date range be enough?

Comment: if you want to generate a report, you also might want to check out advanced filter and pull the content to use that way

Answer (score 0):

Reading a lot into what is certainly not explicit in the question I would suggest (a) possibly use =WEEKNUM to group the reviews by week rather than within a range of dates and (b) apply a PivotTable to show the data not only as required for the report mentioned but also to make good use of other information in the database, for example to show the number of patients scheduled not just for one week but already scheduled for all future weeks.